Prove the area of a quadrilateral $A_1B_1C_1D_1$ has a local minimum at $A_1=A$
$ABCD$ is a cyclic quadrilateral. Its diagonals $AC,BD$ intersect at $P$.
Let $E$ be the point on $AB$ such that $AE:EB=\tan\angle BAP:\tan\angle ABP$.
Let $F$ be the point on $BC$ such that $BF:FC=\tan\angle CBP:\tan\angle BCP$.
Let $G$ be the point on $CD$ such that $CG:GD=\tan\angle DCP:\tan\angle CDP$.
Let $H$ be the point on $DA$ such that $DH:HA=\tan\angle ADP:\tan\angle DAP$.
Let $A_1$ be a point on the line $AP$.
$A_1E$ intersects $BP$ at $B_1$.
$B_1F$ intersects $CP$ at $C_1$.
$C_1G$ intersects $DP$ at $D_1$.
$D_1H$ must intersect $AP$ at $A_1$ (can prove by Menelaus's theorem to $\triangle PAB,\dots,\triangle PDA$).
Points $A,B,C,D$ are fixed, then the area of the quadrilateral $A_1B_1C_1D_1$ depends only on $A_1$.
How to prove that$$\lim_{A_1\to A}\frac{\text{Area}(A_1B_1C_1D_1)-\text{Area}(ABCD)}{|A_1A|}=0\quad\text?$$Equivalently, the area of the quadrilateral $A_1B_1C_1D_1$ has a local minimum at $A_1=A$.


Let $x=\frac{PA_1}{PA}$.
Define the function $f(x)=\frac{\text{Area}(A_1B_1C_1D_1)}{\text{Area}(\triangle PAB)}$. Aim is to prove $f'(1)=0$.
$\frac{PB_1}{PB}=\frac1{1+\frac{BB_1}{PB_1}}=\frac1{1+\frac{BE}{AE}\frac{AA_1}{PA_1}}=\frac1{1+\frac{BE}{AE}(1-\frac1x)}$
$\text{Area}(\triangle PA_1B_1)=\frac{PA_1}{PA}\frac{PB_1}{PB}\text{Area}(\triangle PAB)=\frac{x}{1+\frac{BE}{AE}(1-\frac1x)}\text{Area}(\triangle PAB)$
$\frac{PC_1}{PC}=\frac1{1-\frac{CC_1}{PC_1}}=\frac1{1-\frac{CF}{BF}\frac{BB_1}{PB_1}}=\frac1{1-\frac{CF}{BF}\frac{BE}{AE}(1-\frac1x)}$
$\text{Area}(\triangle PB_1C_1)=\frac{PB_1}{PB}\frac{PC_1}{PC}\text{Area}(\triangle PBC)=\frac1{1+\frac{BE}{AE}(1-\frac1x)}\frac1{1-\frac{CF}{BF}\frac{BE}{AE}(1-\frac1x)}\text{Area}(\triangle PBC)$
$\frac{PD_1}{PD}=\frac1{1+\frac{DD_1}{PD_1}}=\frac1{1+\frac{DH}{AH}\frac{AA_1}{PA_1}}=\frac1{1+\frac{DH}{AH}(1-\frac1x)}$
$\text{Area}(\triangle PC_1D_1)=\frac{PC_1}{PC}\frac{PD_1}{PD}\text{Area}(\triangle PCD)=\frac1{1-\frac{CF}{BF}\frac{BE}{AE}(1-\frac1x)}\frac1{1+\frac{DH}{AH}(1-\frac1x)}\text{Area}(\triangle PCD)$
$\text{Area}(\triangle PD_1A_1)=\frac{PD_1}{PD}\frac{PA_1}{PA}\text{Area}(\triangle PDA)=\frac{x}{1+\frac{DH}{AH}(1-\frac1x)}\text{Area}(\triangle PDA)$
$\text{Area}(\triangle PA_1B_1)+\text{Area}(\triangle PD_1A_1)=x\left(\frac1{1+\frac{BE}{AE}(1-\frac1x)}\text{Area}(\triangle PAB)+\frac1{1+\frac{DH}{AH}(1-\frac1x)}\text{Area}(\triangle PDA)\right)$
$\text{Area}(\triangle PB_1C_1)+\text{Area}(\triangle PC_1D_1)=\frac1{1-\frac{CF}{BF}\frac{BE}{AE}(1-\frac1x)}\left(\frac1{1+\frac{BE}{AE}(1-\frac1x)}\text{Area}(\triangle PBC)+\frac1{1+\frac{DH}{AH}(1-\frac1x)}\text{Area}(\triangle PCD)\right)=\frac1{1-\frac{CF}{BF}\frac{BE}{AE}(1-\frac1x)}\frac{CP}{PA}\left(\frac1{1+\frac{BE}{AE}(1-\frac1x)}\text{Area}(\triangle PAB)+\frac1{1+\frac{DH}{AH}(1-\frac1x)}\text{Area}(\triangle PDA)\right)$
$\text{Area}(A_1B_1C_1D_1)=\left(x+\frac1{1-\frac{CF}{BF}\frac{BE}{AE}(1-\frac1x)}\frac{CP}{PA}\right)\left(\frac1{1+\frac{BE}{AE}(1-\frac1x)}\text{Area}(\triangle PAB)+\frac1{1+\frac{DH}{AH}(1-\frac1x)}\text{Area}(\triangle PDA)\right)$
$f(x)=\frac{\text{Area}(A_1B_1C_1D_1)}{\text{Area}(\triangle PAB)}=\left(x+\frac1{1-\frac{CF}{BF}\frac{BE}{AE}(1-\frac1x)}\frac{CP}{PA}\right)\left(\frac1{1+\frac{BE}{AE}(1-\frac1x)}+\frac1{1+\frac{DH}{AH}(1-\frac1x)}\frac{PD}{PB}\right)$
Substituting $\frac{DH}{AH}=\frac{CF}{BF}$
$$f(x)=\left(x+\frac1{1-\frac{CF}{BF}\frac{BE}{AE}(1-\frac1x)}\frac{CP}{PA}\right)\left(\frac1{1+\frac{BE}{AE}(1-\frac1x)}+\frac1{1+\frac{CF}{BF}(1-\frac1x)}\frac{PD}{PB}\right)$$

\begin{align}
\frac{PD}{PB}&=\frac{\text{dist}(D,AC)}{\text{dist}(B,AC)}\\
&=\frac{\frac{AC}{\cot(\angle DCP)+\cot(\angle DAP)}}{\frac{AC}{\cot(\angle BAP)+\cot(\angle BCP)}}\\
&=\frac{\cot(\angle BAP)+\cot(\angle BCP)}{\cot(\angle DCP)+\cot(\angle DAP)}\\
&=\frac{\cot(\angle BAP)+\cot(\angle BCP)}{\cot(\angle ABP)+\cot(\angle CBP)}\tag1
\end{align}
Similarly
$$\frac{CP}{PA}=\frac{\cot(\angle ABP)+\cot(\angle BCP)}{\cot(\angle CBP)+\cot(\angle BAP)}\tag2$$
Substituting in $\frac{CF}{BF}=\frac{\cot(\angle CBP)}{\cot(\angle BCP)},\frac{BE}{AE}=\frac{\cot(\angle BAP)}{\cot(\angle ABP)}$ and $(1)$ and $(2)$ into $f(x)$, we get $f'(1)=0$.

Mathematica calculation of last step:
D[(x+1/(1-CFBF BEAE (1-1/x))*PCPA)(1/(1+BEAE(1-1/x))+1/(1+CFBF(1-1/x))*PDPB),x]/.{CFBF->CBP/BCP,BEAE->BAP/ABP,PDPB->(BCP+BAP)/(CBP+ABP),PCPA->(ABP+BCP)/(CBP+BAP)}/.x->1//FullSimplify

Output: 0
